# Search function for a binary tree isn't returning the found node

Tags: java, tree, binary-search-tree

This is what I'm inserting into my tree:

I'm searching for: `Node nd = searchNodeIterativly(root, "Ortiz");`

and I'm getting a null pointer error.

Since `"Ortiz"` is actually in the tree, I don't see why my return in the loop isn't working.

Is it the algorithm, or something I'm overlooking?

Here's my code:

```java
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.*;

public class BinaryTree {
    public static class Node {
        String name, number;
        Node Llink, Rlink;
        boolean Ltag, Rtag;

        Node(String name, String number) {
            this.name = name;
            this.number = number;
            Llink = null;
            Rlink = null;
        }
    }

    public static Node insert(Node node, String name, String num) {
        // Searching for a Node with given value
        Node Q = node;
        Node P = null; // Parent of key to be inserted
        while (Q != null) {
            // If key already exists, return
            if (name == (Q.name)) {
                System.out.printf("Duplicate Key !\n");
                return node;
            }
            P = Q;
            if (name.compareTo(Q.name) < 0) {
                if (Q.Ltag == false)
                    Q = Q.Llink;
                else
                    break;
            } else {
                if (Q.Rtag == false)
                    Q = Q.Rlink;
                else
                    break;
            }
        }
        Node tmp = new Node(name, num);
        tmp.name = name;
        tmp.Ltag = true;
        tmp.Rtag = true;

        if (P == null) {
            node = tmp;
            tmp.Llink = null;
            tmp.Rlink = null;
        } else if (name.compareTo(P.name) < 0) {
            tmp.Llink = P.Llink;
            tmp.Rlink = P;
            P.Ltag = false;
            P.Llink = tmp;
        } else {
            tmp.Llink = P;
            tmp.Rlink = P.Rlink;
            P.Rtag = false;
            P.Rlink = tmp;
        }

        return node;
    }

    public static Node searchNodeIterativly(Node node, String name) {
        while (node != null) {
            if (name.compareTo(node.name) > 0) {
                node = node.Llink;
            } else if (name.compareTo(node.name) < 0) {
                node = node.Rlink;
            } else {
                return node;
            }
        }
        return node;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // BinaryTree tree = new BinaryTree();
        Node root = new Node("Moutafis  ", "295-1492");
        insert(root, "Ikerd     ", "291-1864");
        insert(root, "Gladwin   ", "295-1601");
        insert(root, "Robson    ", "293-6122");
        insert(root, "Dang      ", "295-1882");
        insert(root, "Bird      ", "291-7890");
        insert(root, "Harris    ", "294-8075");
        insert(root, "Ortiz     ", "584-3622");

        Node nd = searchNodeIterativly(root, "Ortiz     ");
        if (nd == null) {
            System.out.println("no result found!");
        } else {
            System.out.println(nd.name + ": " + nd.number);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you show the structure of the class Node, especially the method compareTo and method insert?

Comment: "Ortiz" does not equal `"Ortiz            "`.  (the whitespace)

Comment: I just changed it, I thought that would've been it, sadly its still not.

Comment: I think you are going in a wrong way. You have to add the root to the Binary Tree class as an attribut. I made a method to show all the nodes in your tree and it gave me java.lang.StackOverflowError.

Answer (score 0):

Long story short, `searchNodeIteratively`'s logic looks fine, but `insert` is broken because it builds an invalid tree and the classes would benefit from a re-write. Read on for details.

---

These classes flaunt core OOP principles with the most blatant violation being [re-use](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_reuse). If all of the logic in the `BinaryTree` class is [hard coded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_coding) to rely on `name` and `num` properties of the `Node` class, then it's useless for any purpose than storing these exact two fields and we have to re-write the entire class any time our data changes. Using [generics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generics_in_Java), we can allow a `BinaryTree` or `Node` to work with arbitrary types without re-writing any code.

The class organization is unusual--`BinaryTree` enforces uniqueness, so it's really a `BinarySearchTree` class and should be named accordingly. `insert` should return a boolean (whether the insertion succeeded or not) and methods should not be static. `new BinaryTree` in `main` was commented out, but this is the right idea (we want to instantiate a BST). Hiding `Node` inside of `BinaryTree` is also good (it's an implementation detail of a BST), but it should be private.

Other remarks:

- Use `.equals()` instead of `==` to compare objects, as in `name == (Q.name)`; `==` compares memory locations (this may have been your intent here, but then I'd question whether it's the correct logic for what we'd consider unique).
- `Q`, `P` `Rlink` don't explain much about what they are and don't adhere to Java variable naming conventions (use lowerCamelCase). Avoid single-letter variable names unless the meaning is obvious. `String num` is unclear--`String phoneNumber` makes more sense. Instead of writing comments to explain unclear variable names like `Node P = null; // Parent of key to be inserted`, provide a meaningful name like `Node parent = null;` and solve the problem directly.
- Return a value or throw an error instead of printing error messages. Prints are [side effects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side_effect_(computer_science)) that can't be programmatically handled.
- `Ltag` and `Rtag` appear to be redundant information and make the insertion logic very confusing. Just check whether the left and right `Node` objects are `null` to test their existence. This reduces bloat and avoids scenarios where the boolean values get out of sync with the `Node` values.
- The insertion logic:

  ```
  tmp.Llink = P.Llink;
  tmp.Rlink = P;
  ```

  appears to build an invalid tree. This sets the new node (`tmp`)'s left link to point to the parent node's old left link and points the new node's right link to the parent, breaking the definition of a tree, which is a graph with one root and no cycles.
- `searchNodeIterativly` should be called `searchNode` or `contains`. How it accomplishes this (iteratively) should be inconsequential from the perspective of the client of this class (this might be an appropriate name for a private method).
- We can see that `insert` offers no balancing of the tree, so this essentially cripples `contains` and `insert` method complexity to O(n). Adding balancing to the tree would be a good next addition, bringing operations to the desired O(n log(n)).

Here's an initial re-write that implements generics and reusability in the `BinarySearchTree` class. We can invoke `contains` with a lambda function to dynamically search (or we can use an instance of `T` if that makes more sense). These classes only partially implement the class contract--I'd expect `equals` and `hashCode` to be implemented for starters.

```
import java.util.*;

class BinarySearchTree<T extends Comparable<T>> {
    public interface Comparator<T> {
        int compare(T t);
    }

    private static class Node<T extends Comparable<T>> 
              implements Comparable<Node<T>> {
        private T data;
        private Node left;
        private Node right;

        Node(T data, Node left, Node right) {
            this.data = data;
            this.left = left;
            this.right = right;
        }

        @Override
        public int compareTo(Node<T> node) {
            return this.data.compareTo(node.data);
        }
    }

    private Node<T> root;

    public BinarySearchTree() {
        this.root = null;
    }

    public boolean insert(T item) {
        Node<T> prev = null;

        for (var curr = root; curr != null;) {
            prev = curr;

            if (curr.data.compareTo(item) == 0) {
                return false;
            }

            curr = curr.data.compareTo(item) < 0 ? 
                curr.left : curr.right;
        }

        if (prev == null) {
            root = new Node<T>(item, null, null);
        }
        else if (prev.data.compareTo(item) < 0) {
            prev.left = new Node<T>(item, null, null);
        }
        else {
            prev.right = new Node<T>(item, null, null);
        }

        return true;
    }

    public boolean contains(Comparator<T> cmp) {
        for (var curr = root; curr != null;) {
            if (cmp.compare(curr.data) == 0) {
                return true;
            }

            curr = cmp.compare(curr.data) < 0 ? 
                curr.left : curr.right;
        }

        return false;
    }

    public boolean contains(T item) {
        for (var curr = root; curr != null;) {
            if (curr.data.compareTo(item) == 0) {
                return true;
            }

            curr = curr.data.compareTo(item) < 0 ? 
                curr.left : curr.right;
        }

        return false;
    }

    private static void print(Node node, int depth) {
        if (node != null) {
            print(node.left, depth + 4);

            for (int i = 0; i < depth; i++) {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }

            System.out.println(node.data);
            print(node.right, depth + 4);
        }
    }

    public void print() {
        print(root, 0);
    }
}

class Person implements Comparable<Person> {
    private String name;
    private String phone;

    public Person(String name, String phone) {
        this.name = name;
        this.phone = phone;
    }

    public String getName() { return name; }
    public String getPhone() { return phone; }
    public String toString() { return name; }

    public int compareTo(Person person) {
        return name.compareTo(person.name);
    }
}

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[][] data = {
            {"Ikerd", "291-1864"},
            {"Gladwin", "295-1601"},
            {"Robson", "293-6122"},
            {"Dang", "295-1882"},
            {"Bird", "291-7890"},
            {"Harris", "294-8075"},
            {"Ortiz", "584-3622"},
            {"Ortiz", "584-3622"}
        };

        var people = new BinarySearchTree<Person>();

        for (var entry : data) {
            people.insert(new Person(entry[0], entry[1]));
        }

        people.print();
        System.out.println(
            "\nContains \"Bird\"? " + people.contains((p) -> p.getName().compareTo("Bird"))
        );
        System.out.println(
            "Contains \"Birds\"? " + people.contains((p) -> 
                p.getName().compareTo("Birds"))
        );
    }
}
```

Output:

```
    Robson
        Ortiz
Ikerd
        Harris
    Gladwin
        Dang
            Bird

Contains "Bird"? true
Contains "Birds"? false
```